# Devtools failed to load SourceMap in Chrome Versión 84.0.4147.89 (Build official) on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Google Chrome is adding a suffix .map in those urls of my application and I have problems rendering a backbone UI

I see console errors:

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for ../static-content/js/thirdParty/backbone/backbone.marionette.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for ../static-content/js/thirdParty/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for ../static-content/js/thirdParty/backbone/backbone.wreqr.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for ../static-content/js/thirdParty/backbone/backbone.babysitter.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for ../static-content/css/thirdParty/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

In Firefox is not happening and I can render my application correctly

Do you have any idea of what's going on?

Edit: On version 78.0.3904.108 of Google chrome it's not happening.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps in each of those js files there is something like url commented: '/*# sourceMappingURL=dsggdgdg.fdgdfn.dfg.map */'

remove that and you are done

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by **clearing App Data**.

Cypress documentation admits that App Data can get corrupted:

> Cypress maintains some local application data in order to save user preferences and more quickly start up. Sometimes this data can become corrupted. You may fix an issue you have by clearing this app data.

1. Open Cypress via `cypress open`
2. Go to `File` -> `View App Data`
3. This will take you to the directory in your file system where your
   App Data is stored. If you cannot open Cypress, search your file
   system for a directory named `cy` whose content should look something
   like this:

production
             all.log
             browsers
             bundles
             cache
             projects
             proxy
             state.json

4. Delete everything in the `cy` folder
5. Close Cypress and open it up again

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting.html#To-clear-App-Data